# Creating points in specific size

Tags: c#, performance, .net, winforms

The method is in a new class and i use it from form1:
In the top of the new class:

```
public int numberOfPoints = 100;
```

The class Init method:

```
public void Init()
{
    if (IsEmpty(bmpWithPoints) == true)
    {
        bmpWithPoints = GetBitmapWithEllipses(1.0f);
    }
}
```

Then the method:

```
private Bitmap GetBitmapWithEllipses(float radius)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(512, 512);

    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        g.Clear(Color.Black);
        g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

        //store the Ellipses in a GraphicsPath
        using (System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gP = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath())
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < numberOfPoints; x++)
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < numberOfPoints; y++)
                {
                    Color c = Color.FromArgb(
                        r.Next(0, 256),
                        r.Next(0, 256),
                        r.Next(0, 256));

                    using (SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(c))
                    {
                        Point pt = new Point(r.Next(bmp.Width), r.Next(bmp.Height));

                        //clone and widen the path to determine, whether the new point overlaps
                        using (System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath gP2 = (System.Drawing.Drawing2D.GraphicsPath)gP.Clone())
                        {
                            using (Pen pen = new Pen(Brushes.White, radius))
                            {
                                gP2.Widen(pen);
                                while (gP2.IsVisible(pt.X, pt.Y) || gP2.IsOutlineVisible(pt, pen))
                                {
                                    pt = new Point(r.Next(bmp.Width), r.Next(bmp.Height));
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        RectangleF rc = new RectangleF(pt.X - radius, pt.Y - radius, radius * 2, radius * 2);
                        g.FillEllipse(sb, rc);
                        gP.StartFigure();
                        gP.AddEllipse(rc);
                        gP.CloseFigure();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return bmp;
}
```

And in `Form1`:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    textBox1.Text = trackBar1.Maximum.ToString();
    de.pb1 = pictureBox1;

    de.bmpWithPoints = new Bitmap(512, 512);
    de.numberOfPoints = 20;
    de.randomPointsColors = true;
    de.Init();
}
```

When i set the number of points in form1 to 10 for example it will work fast the method and return the bmp with 10 points fast.
But if i set in form1 the number of points to 20 it will take about 3-5 seconds.
If i set it to 50 points in form1 it will take some minutes.

1. What should be the limit maximum points to be able to set ? The size of the image is 512, 512. So it's logical i will be able to fill all the image with points that's 512*512 = 262144 logical i mean by the user. The user can set the number of points and the size of them. In this example it's 1.0f the radius of each point.
2. How can i make it the method `GetBitmapWithEllipses` to create the points faster ?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You gave us code and technical question but you forgot to tell us what it is this code accomplish. To help reviewers give you better answers, please add sufficient context to your question. The more you tell us about what your code does and what the purpose of doing that is, the easier it will be for reviewers to help you. [Questions should include a description of what the code does](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1226)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is unclear.

- You have a variable called `numberOfPoints`, but you are drawing ellipses
- You do the ellipse drawing `numberOfPoints * numberOfPoints` times, therefore the variable should rather be named `sqrtOfNumberOfPoints`
- You work with fully qualified class names instead of importing them, which makes the code harder to read
- The overlapping check takes \$O(n)\$ time, where \$n\$ is the number of previous points
- Altogether, your algorithm is \$O(n^4)\$, where \$n\$ is the `numberOfPoints` (which, as I said, is not the number of points, but its square root)
- It's obvious that running 100*100*100*100 operations takes much longer than 10*10*10*10.
- You don't use the variables `x` and `y` during the loop. Since these names have a clear meaning in graphics (they are coordinates), you are confusing the human reader. Rename them to more innocent names. And, more importantly, combine them to a single loop.